# Firebase error Each then() should return a value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The main purpose is to send a notification to each unser registrated under "Device/(device id)/Users", and to have the device id first I´m looking in "Notifications/notID" which is the "device id" that will be used

I got follow errors when deploy my code

```
✖ 5 problems (1 error, 4 warnings)
   0 errors and 2 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
      additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\luisr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05- 
     22T18_46_41_843Z-debug.log events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "C:\Users\luisr\Documents\Proyectos\HOSI\CloudFunctions\SendNotification\functions" run lint ENOENT
at notFoundError (C:\Users\luisr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\luisr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\luisr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess.cp.emit 
(C:\Users\luisr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase- 
 tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12) {
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix
```

"C:\Users\luisr\Documents\Proyectos\HOSI\CloudFunctions\SendNotification\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "C:\Users\luisr\Documents\Proyectos\HOSI\CloudFunctions\SendNotification\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
]
    Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

I think that I´m not using promises like try/catch

this my index.js file

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');  // this is the Admin SDK, not firebase-functions

    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    const db = admin.database()
    const ms = admin.messaging()

    exports.notifications = functions.database.ref('Notifications/{id}').onUpdate(async(evt) =>{

        const payload = {
            notification:{
                title   : '¡Alarma!',
                body    : 'Se activó tu cerca, revisala',
                badge   : '1',
                sound   :'defaul'   
            }
        };

        //Get Notification Device ID
        const notySnap = await db.ref('Notification/').once('value');

        var devicee = notySnap.notId;
        var dev = JSON.stringify(devicee);


        //Get number of users that the device had
        const usersSnap = await db.ref('Devices/'+ dev + '/Users').once('value')
        const nUsers = usersSnap.nUsers;
        var Nusers = JSON.stringify(nUsers);
        var nNUsers = parseInt(Nusers);


        //Send notification to the number of users that exist
        if (Nusers !== null){
            for(i = 0; 1 <=nNUsers; i++){

                if(i === 1){
                    const userToSendP1 = usersSnap.user1;
                    var userToSend1 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP1);
                    Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 1");
                    ms.sendToDevice(userToSend1, payload);
                }else if(i === 2){
                    const userToSendP2 = usersSnap.user2;
                    var userToSend2 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP2);
                    Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 2");
                    ms.sendToDevice(userToSend2, payload);
                }else if(i === 3){
                    const userToSendP3 = usersSnap.user3;
                    var userToSend3 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP3);
                    Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 3");
                    ms.sendToDevice(userToSend3, payload);
                }else if(i === 4){
                    const userToSendP4 = usersSnap.user4;
                    var userToSend4 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP4);
                    Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 4");
                    ms.sendToDevice(userToSend4, payload);
                }
                /*
                switch(i){
                    case 1:
                        const userToSendP1 = usersSnap.user1;
                        var userToSend1 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP1);
                        Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 1");
                        ms.sendToDevice(userToSend1, payload);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        const userToSendP2 = usersSnap.user2;
                        var userToSend2 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP2);
                        Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 2");
                        ms.sendToDevice(userToSend2, payload);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        const userToSendP3 = usersSnap.user3;
                        var userToSend3 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP3);
                        Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 3");
                        ms.sendToDevice(userToSend3, payload);
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        const userToSendP4 = usersSnap.user4;
                        var userToSend4 = JSON.stringify(userToSendP4);
                        Console.log("Mensaje enviado a user 4");
                        ms.sendToDevice(userToSend4, payload);
                        break;
                }*/
            }
        }
        return response.send("Sended Notification").status(200);
    });
```

Comment: Those warnings and errors don't look at all related to this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error but a eslint rule which is configured to show such issue as an error.

[promise/always-return](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/always-return.md) request that every `then` function returns a value.

The code you provided doesn't have any `then` callback. Are you sure you are looking at right place?

Comment: Is the only js that I have in the cloud function.

Comment: I update with the hole error.